# HTML object VBA

Tags: html, vba

I need to enter to this button but I can't find the name, Id or anything which help me to identify the bottom.

This is the code in HTML.

```html
<a href="#" id="populateItemList" marker="stepnameinlist" stepname="Create Third Party Customer" items="11">Create Third Party Customer</a>
```

What code can I use in VAB to connect with this button?

This is the code:

VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://zvc-t-mdmap01:7507/utils/enterLogin.jsp"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document

    End With

    html.getElementById("username").Value = Sheets("InfoSphere").Range("i4")
    html.getElementById("password").Value = Sheets("InfoSphere").Range("i5")
    html.getElementById("company_code").Value = Sheets("InfoSphere").Range("i6")
    html.getElementById("loginButton_label").Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://zvc-t-mdmap01:7507/worklist/worklistconsole.jsp?colAreaName=Third%20Party%20Customer%20Management%20Process"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document

    End With

    Set link = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each l In link

        If l.innerText = "Create Third Party Customer" Then
            l.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next l

    'Add

    IE.document.querySelector("[stepname='Create Third Party Customer']").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using IE automation through microsoft internet controls? Also, that is not a button you are showing but a link. Is it inside a button tag element? The element you are showing has an id.

Comment: Yes, this is a link but I don't know how to identify it in VBA. I was looking the ID and it is the same for differents Link for that reason I can't use it.

Comment: You should work with the one instance of IE and keep the With statement open rather than open two instances of IE which is what you are doing - unless you need them both? (which doesn't seem to be the case for your given code)

Comment: I already deleted one IE instance but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try an attribute = value selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[stepname='Create Third Party Customer']").click
```

---

Brute force approach:

```
Dim aTags As Object, aTag As Object
Set aTags = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
Dim event_onClick As Object
Set event_onClick = html.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
event_onClick.initEvent "click", True, False
For Each aTag In aTags
    If InStr(aTag.outerHTML, "Create Third Party Customer") > 0 Then
        With aTag
            .Click
            .dispatchEvent event_onClick
             .FireEvent "onclick"
        End With
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I receive this error : "Object doesn't support this property or method" this is the complete code

Comment: That's right, when I use ele as object I receive the same error. "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Yes , it stops in this line. Set ele = IE.document.querySelector("[stepname='Create Third Party Customer']")

Comment: oh... what is the error for that? doesn't support this property?

Comment: Yes, that is the error. "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: 1) what version of IE are you running? 2) if you go dev > tools > emulation tab > what is the document mode?

Comment: I'm running 11 Version. Document mode 5(Default)

Comment: So v11 is fine. Is default = Edge? If not, can you manually alter to Edge in a normally opened instance of IE (not via code) and try running code again.

Comment: I have also added another approach to try.

Comment: It didn't work but I don't receive an error either, I already added the final code

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work but I don't receive an error either, this is the final code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim aTags As Object, aTag As Object


With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://zvc-t-mdmap01:7507/utils/enterLogin.jsp"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document

html.getElementById("username").Value = Sheets("InfoSphere").Range("i4")
html.getElementById("password").Value = Sheets("InfoSphere").Range("i5")
html.getElementById("company_code").Value = Sheets("InfoSphere").Range("i6")
html.getElementById("loginButton_label").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))


        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://zvc-t-mdmap01:7507/worklist/worklistconsole.jsp?colAreaName=Third%20Party%20Customer%20Management%20Process"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document

End With

'Add


Set aTags = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each aTag In aTags
    If InStr(aTag.outerHTML, "Create Third Party Customer") > 0 Then
        aTag.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```